# Saving a MLLib decision tree model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, decision-tree

I have a decision tree in MLLib scala:

```
    val tree = model.stages(1).asInstanceOf[DecisionTreeClassificationModel]
```

I would like to save this model to disk or to hdfs. When I type tree.save(...) it throws a compilation error basically pointing to no such method for the model.

Any pointers would be greatly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The DecisionTreeClassificationModel doesn't have a save method in it, hence throwing the following error. In order to save it to disk or hdfs you need to have a RDD of the objects which you want to save to disk. For this you can create a RDD[DecisionTreeClassificationModel] and then use the corresponding save methods available.

Comment: I am not able to see how you do that. Could you please give me a scala code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `save` method belongs to:

> `org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel`

not `DecisionTreeClassificationModel` which is in `org.apache.spark.ml.classification`